# Will upgrading matlab from 2009b to 2015 improve performance of mex Functions?

Tags: matlab

I am currently using Matlab 2009b to run optimizations based on mex code. The time spent in numerous calls to mex function is more than 95%. I am currently using cygwin64 compiler on windows machine, which is setup using gnumex.

I want to know if there will be noticeable decrease in optimization time if I upgrade my matlab to 2015.

The release notes at matlab (http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html) mentions several performance improvements over the course of various release but if somebody can quantify it, it can be useful to make my decision.

Comment: Is this not something you could ask your local Matlab distributor to verify for you? They can probably give you a 30 free trial for example that you could test it yourself with?

Comment: Thank you Dan. Certainly that is an option I can explore. I hoped if somebody had experience with this before me, it could save me the time.

Comment: I suspect this is very much code-dependent, so the best option would be to try it, as @Dan suggested.

Comment: Doubtless there have been several other improvements at least and as far as I know, the cost for a license is not lower because you use an older version of matlab. So I cannot see a reason to refrain from trying...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested it with 2015a and the difference in performance was less than 2 seconds in a 90 minute test. It appears the mex performance does not depend on matlab version.